# How to select a button from a interactive message with a bot?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm trying to get a bot to "click" a button on an interactive message in Slack (preferably as a bot, but using a user token works too).

I've found that the link to send the action information to be

> https://blue-hybrid.slack.com/api/chat.attachmentAction

My problem is I can't find any documentation for "chat.attachmentAction." Looking at the request sent when using my browser, it has one http argument: "_x_id" and the payload is a WebKitForm, containing 4 items: payload, client_id, payload_id, and token.

I'm sure if I'm just not sending the appropriate data or authentication or what. All of my POSTs return "invalid_payload" or "invalid_arg_name."

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The official Slack API does not provide any methods that allow bots to click on buttons afaik. They also do not provide methods for bots to use slash commands btw. The method you found might work, you just need to figure out the right parameters.

Comment: With the parameters `_x_id` and `client_token` this looks very much like an internal API method, that is not available to 3rd party developers.

Comment: This is the command that is used whenever someone clicks a button in an interactive message. At the very least, I'd like to be able to use this command without the need for cookies using my user token. Are there any good tools for reverse engineering this from the browser maybe?

Comment: I agree it would be great to have this feature in the official API. But as I see it this method is locked and can only be used internally by Slack. Therefore i would suggest to send a mail to Slack support asking for this new feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I figured it out, finally!
I had to work it out the old fashioned way. Slack Customer Support would only help with the official public API. I'll leave the solution here in Javascript.

To do this, you need 3 things:

1. `choice_num`

   - the number of the choice within the list of options.
   - e.g. If a message has the buttons (from left to right): yes, no, and maybe, then yes=0, no=1 and maybe=2.
2. `message`

   - the json of the interactive message
3. `SLACK_TOKEN`

   - your slack token (not sure if bot tokens work, user tokens do however)

The method `chat.attachmentAction` itself requires 3 arguments:

- `payload`
- `service_id` AND/OR `bot_user_id`
- `token`

> args = encodeURI(
>   'payload={'
>   + '"actions":[' + JSON.stringify(message.attachments[0]["actions"][choice_num]) + '],'
>   + '"attachment_id":"' + message.attachments[0]["id"] + '",'
>   + '"callback_id":"' + message.attachments[0]["callback_id"] + '",'
>   + '"channel_id":"' + message.channel + '",'
>   + '"message_ts":"' + message.ts + '"}'
>   + '&service_id=' + message.bot_id
>   + '&bot_user_id=' + message.user
>   + '&token=' + SLACK_TOKEN
>   )
>
> request_url = 'https://YOURSLACKTEAM.slack.com/api/chat.attachmentAction?' + args

then just send an async POST to the request_url and you should get back something like this:

> {"replaced":true,"ok":true}